# is three.js safe? where does the data go?

Tags: three.js

im currently doing an offer for a client and need to know a few things before i can move along. id like to state that im an absolute beginner. a 3d artist in fact and im doing this research to see if i would be able to learn this in a relatively short amount of time.

my main concern is data management. if for example i have sensitive data (medical setting) that cant be "open" to the public, where and how can i ensure this data doesnt get out?

also if like ti know: lets say im a doctor and i have a patient. in my web based program i have a 3d model of the patient. A, can i mark positions on the body that are being saved for each patient? B, can i add comments to those marked areas? is this possible? if so, what do i need to know on y basic level to do this?

would my client be able to take my three.js thing and plug it into their website without any problems?

thanks for the time, much appreciated

---

Answer (score 1):

> if for example i have sensitive data (medical setting) that cant be "open" to the public, where and how can i ensure this data doesnt get out?

As with any other software, you need to understand what the software libraries that you use do and if necessary audit their source code.

As especially complicating for web software, your code is run in an inherently connected environment and you can't just tell the runtime / operating system to kill your process when it starts sending data somewhere else – that's literally what browsers do by design.

> is three.js safe?

That's not for me to answer. There's actually mandatory standards for software systems handling sensitive patients data in Europe (and I guess, elsewhere as well!), so I guess you'll have to consult with your local laws about what "safe" means. Chances are, really, that if this is your first forage into programming, patient data is *not* what you want to work on *alone*. However, what you propose in software sounds relatively big anyway, with the "putting markers in 3D space on a model" being one of the smaller problems (getting the model in there, saving the annotations somewhere, this being diagnostically relevant meaning that this requires legally proper archival, possibly… there's a lot of things to do beyond just putting markers in 3D), so I bet you want to work with at least another developer anyway; maybe they have experience in that?

> lets say im a doctor and i have a patient. in my web based program i have a 3d model of the patient. A, can i mark positions on the body that are being saved for each patient? B, can i add comments to those marked areas? is this possible? if so, what do i need to know on y basic level to do this?

Possible: yes. Three.js is a 3D library. It's not a patient annotation library. Everything between displaying a 3D model and navigating 3D space and the marked positions somehow ending up in a patient file,  that's yours to program. Have fun :-) ! This sounds like a good thing.